# How to check if the days are day after day?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if the days in array are day after day?

```
var days = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03']; //should return true

var days2 = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03', '2017-03-04']; //should return false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the following code:

```js
var days = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03']; //should return true
var days2 = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03', '2017-03-04']; //should return false
var days3 = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-02', '2017-04-03']; // should also return false

function dayCheck(daysArray) {
  for (var i = 1; i < daysArray.length; i++) {
    var d = new Date(daysArray[i - 1]);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    if (new Date(daysArray[i]).getTime() != d.getTime())
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(dayCheck(days));
console.log(dayCheck(days2));
console.log(dayCheck(days3));
```

Basically, you take each date, you increment it and check if it matches the next date in the array.

**Update**

As pointed out, using `getDate()` would fail for something like the array values in `days3`, so I changed the code to use `getTime()` instead, which seems more robust.

Comment: Wouldn't this code fail for this case: `['2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-04-02', '2017-04-03']` ?

Comment: @zahirdhada Great observation, actually. Updated to use `getTime()`, should not be a problem any more!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this,

```
function areDatesSequential(days) {
    var seq = true;
    var d = new Date(days[0]);
    for(var i=1;i<days.length;i++) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        var d2 = new Date(days[i]);
        if(d.getDate() != d2.getDate()
            || d.getMonth() != d2.getMonth()
            || d.getFullYear() != d2.getFullYear()) {
            seq = false;
        }
    }

    return seq;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var days = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-01', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03'];
// convert to timestamp
var timestamps = days.map(function(day){
     var date = new Date(day);
     return date.getTime();
});
console.log(timestamps);
var result = true;
for(var i = 1 /*from second el*/; i < timestamps.length; i++) {
    // console.log(timestamps[i] - timestamps[i - 1]);
    if (timestamps[i] - timestamps[i - 1] !== 86400000/* one day in milliseconds*/) {
        result = false;
        break;
    }
}
console.log('res', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function comp( date)
{
    var dates = date;
    var flag = false;
    for( var i = 0 ; i < dates.length-1; i++)
    {
        var firstdate  = new Date(dates[i]);
        firstdate.setDate(firstdate.getDate() + 1);
        var seconddate  = new Date(dates[i+1]);
        if(seconddate.getTime() == firstdate.getTime())
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            flag = false;
            return flag;
        }

    }
    return flag;
}

function compare()
{
    var days = ['2017-02-28', '2017-03-02', '2017-03-03', '2017-03-04'];
    var abc = comp(days);
}
```